# gitlab central repository for all maven artifacts?

Tags: maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci

We are using gitlab and so far we are only missing one feature and we yet could not find out how to achieve that - or if it is even possible.

Currently, if some of our artifacts are dependend on other artifacts from our gitlab, we have to add each dependency separately in our maven *settings.xml*. So if we have project **a**
for example and it is dependend on project **b**, **c**, and **d** we have to do the following:

```xml
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>our-gitlab-maven-project-b</id>
            <configuration>
                <httpHeaders>
                    <property>
                        <name>Private-Token</name>
                        <value>[Token]</value>
                    </property>
                </httpHeaders>
            </configuration>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>our-gitlab-maven-project-c</id>
            <configuration>
                <httpHeaders>
                    <property>
                        <name>Private-Token</name>
                        <value>[Token]</value>
                    </property>
                </httpHeaders>
            </configuration>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>our-gitlab-maven-procject-d</id>
            <configuration>
                <httpHeaders>
                    <property>
                        <name>Private-Token</name>
                        <value>[Token]</value>
                    </property>
                </httpHeaders>
            </configuration>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

Ofcourse it would be much better if we would only have to do something like this:

```xml
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>our-gitlab-repo-where-all-maven-artifacts-are-available</id>
            <configuration>
                <httpHeaders>
                    <property>
                        <name>Private-Token</name>
                        <value>[Token]</value>
                    </property>
                </httpHeaders>
            </configuration>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

Is that possible with gitlab?

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible. Simply start using a repository manager something like Nexus, Artifactory and you have it. Only single credentials ...

Comment: Thx. I already thought so. Feels like a feature missing for gitlab.

Comment: i think it's possible now, if artifat group matches gitlab url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a bit old now but you should be able to achieve this using [the group level](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#endpoint-urls), i.e., `https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/groups/<group_id>/-/packages/maven` as repo URL when all your projects belong to a group. Or several groups otherwise. Or use the instance level if you got your own instance.

Just make sure your package names are unique / you disallow overwriting existing ones.